# AngularJS: Why doesn't the scope item update in my templateUrl but does in my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive like so in my HTML...

```
<div data-navigation>
  <div class="pull-left"><img src="/images/my-site-logo-tiny.png"></div> 
  <div class="pull-right"><h2>My Site Name</h2></div>
</div>
```

and here is my JavaScript

```
.directive('navigation', function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'navigation.html',
            link: function (scope, element) {

                scope.showMenu = {
                    status: false
                };

                element.bind('click', function (){
                    scope.showMenu.status = !scope.showMenu.status;
                    console.log(scope.showMenu.status); // with each click this outputs correctly
                });

            };
});
```

Whilst in my `navigation.html` template I have the following, notice that I am writing `showMenu.status` to the view to see if this is updated...

```
<div data-ng-transclude></div>
{{ showMenu.status }}
<div data-ng-show="showMenu.status">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

When I click on my directive the link function outputs the correct value of `scope.showMenu.status` but the `showMenu.status` is never updated in my template? It remains `false` regardless of clicking. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added a scope.$apply(); to the bind event and everything is cool!

Answer (score 1):

So angular has something called `Angular context`, which gets "injected" into the browser event loop. When an event is fired, the javascript will run and then the appropriate DOM changes will be made.

That is the normal event loop. Having angular, when an event is fired and angular is **notified**, angular will manage that event, run angular stuff and when it is the turn to run the DOM updates, your bindings will get updated as well.

How is angular notified then? Calling `$scope.$apply()`. That is what kicks the `angular context`.

The click event of your example is a classic browser event and that is not managed by the `Angular context` so you have to notify angular

The proper way to do it is:

```
element.bind('click', function (){
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.showMenu.status = !scope.showMenu.status;
  });
});
```

And never

```
element.bind('click', function (){
  scope.showMenu.status = !scope.showMenu.status;
  scope.$apply();
});
```

What you run **inside** an `$apply` is done inside a `try - catch` so if there is any error, the angular exception handler can be notified. That is really useful if you have some kind of notification (like a toast) if there is any error.